# Query to display zero it the sum of entries of the particular month is 0

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm preaty weak in sqlite queries .

I have an set of entries in the sqlite database. I want to find the sum, grouped in months.

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) quantity, strftime('%m', CREATED_ON) month FROM OrderItemBIT  WHERE (strftime('%Y%m',CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '201210' AND '201303') group by month
```

The problem is that if there is no entry for an particular month, I want that entry should display count as zero, but now its not showing anything.

Ex. guess there no entry for the month of Jan for the above query. then it should display the Quantity as 0.

Can anyone help to solve this problem!!!
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, is to create a temp table contain a list of month names, then `JOIN` it with your table. Or you can create it on the fly; something like:

```
SELECT
  m.MonthName,
  IFNULL(SUM(o.QUANTITY), 0) quantity 
FROM
(
  SELECT 'January' AS MonthName
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'March'
  UNION ALL
  ...
) AS Months
LEFT JOIN OrderItemBIT AS o ON o.month = strftime('%m', o.CREATED_ON)
WHERE (strftime('%Y%m', o.CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '201210' AND '201303')
group by m.MonthName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT SUM(COALESCE(QUANTITY, 0))
         , strftime('%m', CREATED_ON) month
    FROM OrderItemBIT
   WHERE (strftime('%Y%m',CREATED_ON) BETWEEN '201210' AND '201303')
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: Then maybe use `SUM(ISNULL(QUANTITY, 0))` or even try `IFFNULL`. The key here is that if there is a record with `NULL` value in `SUM`, it returns `NULL`. So, use a function inside `SUM` to replace the `NULL` values with a `0`.

Comment: But there are no records with `NULL` values, there are no records.

Comment: There are no records at all?

Comment: Well then in that case, use `ISNULL(SUM(ISNULL(QUANTITY, 0)), 0)`. In case of any error, let me know.